# Can't replace nested objects in appsettings file Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Using ReplaceTokens@3:

I have an appsettings.json file which has an object like so:

```
{
   "Data": {
      "myProperty": "#{myProperty}#"
    }
   "myProperty2" : "{myProperty2}"
}
```

In my devops variable group library that is injected into my AzureDevops build, I have a key of `Data.myProperty` and

```
myProperty2
```

Then I use the replace tokens task with prefix of '#{' and suffix of '}#' and target my file.

The log says 2 of 2 replaced, but when I review  the outputted artifact, `Data.myProperty` has not been replaced, yet `myProperty2` has.

What is the correct syntax to target nested object properties?

Comment: Hope answer provided works for your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacetoken task works on Token Pattern regardless of your object is nested or not. So for your case, json file and replace token should be like.

**Json File:**

```
{
       "Data": {
          "myProperty": "#{myProperty}#"
        },
       "myProperty2" : "#{myProperty2}#"
    }
```

[image]

This was variable group attached to pipeline.

[image]

I have tested it and this was resulting json file.

[image: { "Data": { "myProperty": "FirstProperty" }, "myProperty2" : "SecondProperty" }]